# SQL Sever Intellectual Property (Protect Data Structure from End Client DBA)

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, encryption

I would like to know is there any update about protecting DB Structure?

We deliver a licensed app that uses SQL as its main DBMS and we would like to lock the database structure (schema).

I know I can encrypt the data it self and stored procedure ...etc. I want the best practice to encrypt/Secure/ Lock the data structure and relation from end client DBA.

I have access to the end client physical server as we make the app installation and repair.

The app is written in C# using linq to sql

Microsoft is not providing this function as per:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/protecting-your-sql-server-intellectual-property?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Good question, I think you will get a better answer in this Stack Exchange site : https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks I will post it there as well :)